# Regex get between 2 string with spaces

Tags: regex

how could I parse this response text using Regex?

```
info = {
    "title": "Developers",
    "image": "http://i.ytimg.com/vi/KMU0tzLwhbE/default.jpg",
    "length": "3",
    "status": "serving",
    "progress_speed": "",
    "progress": "",
    "ads": "",
    "pf": "http://70efd.pf.aclst.com/ping.php/10754233/KMU0tzLwhbE?h=882634",
    "h": "87d0670f6822946338a610a6b9ec5322",
    "px": ""
  };
```

The outcome I need should look like this "87d0670f6822946338a610a6b9ec5322", however, I can't get the correct syntax. I'm new to using Regex and what I have tried using is "\s+", can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What flavor of regex are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you must use a regex, you could use a regex along the lines of:

`"h" : "(.+?)",`

You can see an example of it [here](http://rubular.com/r/PW5pEUQCBt). Just read from the first capture group and that would select your text.

That looks like like JSON aside from the `info =` prefix. If you have any specific language you are working in that could parse JSON, that might be a better way of handling that input.

Comment: Good catch, greedyness gets me every time. :)

Comment: thanx this is usefully for me

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `(?<="h": ")[a-z0-9]+(?=")`, which will match any sequence of lowercase letters and numbers, as long as the sequence is preceded by `"h": "` and followed by `"`. I made an explanation and demonstration [here](http://regex101.com/r/dR4vX3/1).